# LogonUI.exe process doesn't terminate after switching user

Tags: windows, authentication, credential-providers

I am developing a **Credential Provider (CP)** that shows a dialog at logon or unlock screen of Windows Vista/7. That dialog terminates whenever the destructor of my Credential Provider is invoked. For basic scenarios like unlock or logon, that dialog is closed properly; however, I got into trouble with this scenario:

1. Lock computer: this will show my dialog
2. Click "Other Credentials"
3. Click "Switch User"

After step 3, a new dialog is created (a new `logonUI` process creates my **CP**) but the dialog in step 1 still exist but hide. I tried to debug and found that the `loginUI` created in the step 1 is not terminated and still keeps my CP so it is not destructed , then the dialog is not closed.

I expect there is only one dialog exist at a time. Is there any way to ask `logonUI` to release my **CP** or catch switch user event so that I can close the dialog on my own?

I am using: Win7 32-bit Ultimate.

Comment: maybe, just each time when SetUsageScenario is called, check whenever any dialog exist, and if so, just destroy it, and create new.

Comment: I think you need to support multiple simultaneous dialogs.  What if two people are trying to log on (or unlock) simultaneously?